# git clone not using configured SSH key

Tags: git, ssh

I have a repo hosted at `http://git.example.com/repo.git`.

On one certain computer ("Computer 1"), I'm able to run `git clone http://git.example.com/repo.git` and it works just fine because I have my `~/.ssh/config` configured to use a certain username and private key for `git.example.com`.

On a different computer ("Computer 2"), I have `~/.ssh/config` set identically, and I have the same exact public and private keys from Computer 1 sitting in the `~/.ssh` directory of Computer 2. However, when I run `git clone http://git.example.com/repo.git` from Computer 2, I get prompted `Username for 'http://git.example.com'`, apparently meaning Computer 2 is not successfully reading the `~/.ssh/config` setting saying which username and SSH key to use.

So, two different computers, identical configuration AFAICT, yet one works and the other doesn't.

How can I troubleshoot/fix this?

**Edit**: I should add that `ssh my-user@git.example.com` from Computer 2 works fine, meaning my `~/.ssh/config` works as expected for that purpose, just not cloning my repo.

Also, my cloning MUST happen over HTTP/HTTPS, not any other protocol, so any solution that's not HTTP/HTTPS won't work for me.

Comment: SSH keys have no effect on HTTP and HTTPS.  They are only used for the SSH protocol, which is separate and independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you clone `http[s]://git.example.com/repo.git`  you must use a kind of http authentification .

if you clone  `git@git.example.com/repo.git`  you are using ssh , so it can be password or key authentification .

please run `git config  remote.origin.url` in you folder to see what is the url

and  you must check that `ssh git@git.example.com` is working

Comment: Thanks, this steered me in the right direction. I'll add that I found this post helpful: https://maymay.net/blog/2008/08/08/how-to-use-http-basic-authentication-with-git/